# Azure Active Directory Refresh Token for iOS client

Tags: ios, azure, azure-mobile-services, access-token

I have a standard iOS app from QuickStart downloaded from my portal like so:

[image]

Its a very basic iOS app that communicates with the Azure backend where you can push and pull data.

#### log in, log out

If you are to turn on authentication in your portal, you will need to log in. You do so like this:

```
[client loginWithProvider:@"windowsazureactivedirectory"
                   controller:controller
                     animated:YES
                   completion:^(MSUser *user, NSError *error) {
          // save data into your keychain
          // invoke various custom APIs
          // be able to pull and push data to your Easy Table
}];
```

Log out is also simple:

```
[client logoutWithCompletion:^(NSError * _Nullable error) {

    if(!error) {
        [self clearCredentials];
        complete(nil);
    } else {
        DDLogError(@"%@", [error debugDescription]);
        complete(error);
    }

}];
```

#### Refreshing the Token

My problem is the token. I understand that when using Active Directory, the token they give you lasts for 1 hour only. If you were to get a Refresh token, you need to use it within 14 days. If you do use it within 14 days, it will be good up to 90 days after that.

Hence, I waited an hour, and when I try using the client to pull data or invoke an API, it would give me an 401 error:

```
    Error Domain=com.Microsoft.MicrosoftAzureMobile.ErrorDomain Code=-1301 "The server returned an error." UserInfo={com.Microsoft.MicrosoftAzureMobile.ErrorResponseKey= { URL: https://xxxx-xxxxxx.azurewebsites.net/api/getUserProfileData } { status code: 401, headers {
        "Content-Length" = 0;
        Date = "Tue, 25 Oct 2016 09:18:57 GMT";
        Server = "Microsoft-IIS/8.0";
        "Set-Cookie" = "ARRAffinity=743d3a9e04f3c081f27c2f2c3af95d099f93dc60f14553bd4423b0abc62cfd33;Path=/;Domain=xxxx-xxxxxx.azurewebsites.net";
        "Www-Authenticate" = "Bearer realm=\"xxxx-xxxxxx.azurewebsites.net\"";
        "X-Powered-By" = "ASP.NET";
    } }, NSLocalizedDescription=The server returned an error., com.Microsoft.MicrosoftAzureMobile.ErrorRequestKey= { URL: https://xxxx-xxxxxx.azurewebsites.net/api/getUserProfileData }}
```

The log for my custom node script that the client hits, gives 401.71 unauthorized error:

```
    2016-10-25T09:18:55  PID[35372] Warning     JWT validation failed: IDX10223: Lifetime validation failed. The token is expired.
    ValidTo: '10/25/2016 09:12:31'
    Current time: '10/25/2016 09:18:55'..
    2016-10-25T09:18:55  PID[35372] Information Sending response: 401.71 Unauthorized
```

If I were to do a pull down on my table to grab data:

```
        com.Microsoft.MicrosoftAzureMobile.ErrorRequestKey= { URL: https://xxx-xxxxx.azurewebsites.net/tables/TodoItem?$skip=0&$filter=(updatedAt%20ge%20datetimeoffset'2016-10-20T02%3A33%3A25.607Z')&$orderby=updatedAt%20asc&__includeDeleted=true&$top=50 }}
     code - -1301
     domain - com.Microsoft.MicrosoftAzureMobile.ErrorDomain
    userInfo - {
        NSLocalizedDescription = "The server returned an error.";
        "com.Microsoft.MicrosoftAzureMobile.ErrorRequestKey" = " { URL: https://xxxx-xxxxxx.azurewebsites.net/tables/TodoItem?$skip=0&$filter=(updatedAt%20ge%20datetimeoffset'2016-10-20T02%3A33%3A25.607Z')&$orderby=updatedAt%20asc&__includeDeleted=true&$top=50 }";
```

Microsoft Azure has a small article on refreshing tokens here:
https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/blog/mobile-apps-easy-authentication-refresh-token-support/

I would use refreshUserWithCompletion: method, but it keeps giving me 403 error.

Hence, if anyone have successfully refreshed their token on an iOS app, please comment.

thank you!

UPDATE: REFRESH WORKS, TOKEN STILL EXPIRES IN 1 HOUR

After following the links, my refreshUserWithCompletion method works, and returns a valid MSUser object with token. **However**, the issue is that this token is still only good for 1 hour. I'm pasting my refresh token code below. Please suggest, thanks!

```
if(!client.currentUser) {

    [client loginWithProvider:@"windowsazureactivedirectory"
                   controller:controller
                     animated:YES
                   completion:^(MSUser * user, NSError *error) {

        DDLogInfo(@"INITIAL TOKEN, userId: %@, token: %@", user.userId, user.mobileServiceAuthenticationToken);

        if(!error && user) {

            [client refreshUserWithCompletion:^(MSUser * _Nullable user, NSError * _Nullable error) {
                // user object now has new token for us to use. 
                // I'm assuming this is the refresh token.

                [self saveUserIntoKeyChain: user];
                // I can just load the userId and token from the keychain for future uses, and they all work. 
                // The only problem is that this token is only good for 1 hour.

            }];
        }
    }];
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

AAD requires configuration for refresh.  See my blog on the subject: https://shellmonger.com/2016/04/13/30-days-of-zumo-v2-azure-mobile-apps-day-7-refresh-tokens/

If you haven't configured refresh, it isn't available.  Once you do configure refresh, then the NEXT time you log in, you will get a refresh token that can be re-used.

Comment: I went through that link, as well as Chris Gillum's link. I followed all the changes and applied them to my configurations.

I can now use the refreshUserWithCompletion method to refresh my MSUser object. It returns a new MSUser object along with a new token. 

However, the issue is that this token is still only good for 1 hour. Whenever I try to refresh my Easy Table (or invoke other APIs) on that client after an hour, it would still give me a 401 error. I first call loginWithProvider, then I call the refreshUserWithCompletion. I then save the returned user object to my keychain.

Comment: Trap the 401 error - when you get one, follow logic that covers all the situations - cached credentials, refresh tokens, etc.  Chapter 2 of the C# version of the book has the ordering I suggest - http://aka.ms/zumobook - it's in C#/.NET, but the logic is the same.